# Show the function is continuous in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Show that the function f is continuous in $\Bbb R^2$ :
$$f(x,y)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ 1cc}
             \sin(xy)/xy  & xy\neq0\\
             \\ 1, & xy =0 \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

I thought by computing the partial derivatives.

Comment: To compute the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$, you'll need to go back to their definition in terms of limits&mdash;and this would seem to be no simpler than dealing showing $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0) f(x, y) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By the definition of continuity, you must check that: $$\lim_{(x,y) \to \,{\bf 0}}\frac{\sin(xy)}{xy} = 1.$$

However, $g(x,y) = xy$ is continuous (polynomial), hence $xy \to 0$ as $(x,y)\to {\bf 0}$, and you have the fundamental limit $\sin(t)/t \to 1$ as $t \to 0$. So?

Answer (score 0):

The function

$$ g(t) = \begin{cases} (\sin t) /t, \,\,t\ne 0 \\ 
1, \,\,t=0\end{cases}$$

is real analytic on $\mathbb {R}.$ Because $h(x,y)=xy$ is real analytic on $\mathbb {R}^2,$ and compositions of real analytic functions are real analytic, $g \circ h$ is real analytic on $\mathbb {R}^2.$ But $f$ is precisely $g \circ h,$ and so $f$ is real analytic on $\mathbb {R}^2,$ which gives us much more than continuity on $\mathbb {R}^2.$